# Why does jQuery UI's droppable `accept` function run when nothing is over it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an accept function defined on the red box in the fiddle.

**Expected**

Accept runs once when draggable enters it.

**Actual**

Accept seems to run once when drag enters, once when it leaves, and many, many times if I drag the yellow box to left of the HTML screen.

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/bjJv8/

I am not asking how to avoid this; I can write my own revert functionality, but the main reason it seems I have to is because this doesn't seem to work right.

To see what I'm saying, drag the yellow box to the left of the screen. You'll see the accept counter increments every drag pixel. What is going on? Why does `accept` run so many times when nothing is dragged onto it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept can be either a selector (typically a class) describing the items that can be dragged into the droppable, or a function that will return true if the object passed to it can be dropped on the target.

Inconveniently, it seems the accept function is run on every drag event (start, stop, enter, leave), as well as on drags along the edge of the page. If your accept function is going to get quite large, you might want to put it in the drop/stop method, and revert if it is an invalid drop.

Alternately, you could start off the accept function by determining whether the item has been dropped or is being dropped, and only do the heavy lifting in that case (otherwise return true, see note below).

Side note: if `accept` returns false on drag start, it doesn't run for any of the other events (except dragging along the edge of the page).

Comment: According to docs: "All draggables that match the selector will be accepted. **If a function is specified**, the function will be called for each draggable on the page (passed as the first argument to the function), to provide a custom filter. The function should return true if the draggable should be accepted."

Comment: Oh. Had some trouble finding the docs for it, so I just answered from memory.

Comment: Interesting. It runs on startdrag, stopdrag, enter, leave, sometimes on move, and many times when reaching the edge of the page... basically for any event.

Comment: Yah it seems wrong to me, that's why I was so confused. My accept logic in my app has the potential to be complex and I don't want it running 50x a second.

Comment: I changed it to jQuery 1.7.1 and UI 1.8.16 and it's better, but if you drag along the edge of the redbox on the left side, it still does it.

Comment: It seems most of the running (aside from the start/stop/enter/leave events) is triggered from moving while near the edge of the page. Putting a margin on the target and drag classes reduces this effect. There is still the matter of it firing on all events.

Comment: @subkamran I've updated my answer a bit. There's a suggestion that may be workable.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing (handling in `drop`).